# How to inject HttpContextBase using Autofac in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I am using `ASP.MVC 4` and `Autofac`.

I have registered the following in my `global.asax.cs` file:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Request)
     .As<HttpRequestBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Response)
     .As<HttpResponseBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Server)
     .As<HttpServerUtilityBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Session)
     .As<HttpSessionStateBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType<WebWorkContext>().As<IWorkContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

In my Home controller I have this (just for testing purposes):

```
private readonly HttpContextBase httpContext;

public HomeController(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
     this.httpContext = httpContext;
}
```

I used the exact same code with an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and it worked fine.  Now in this project I am getting errors.  Not sure why?  The error that I am getting is:

**None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyProject.Web.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:  Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Web.HttpContextBase)'.     at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)     at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<**

I'm not too sure why this won't work?  Do I need to do things differently in ASP.NET 4?

I have a separate project in which I also want to inject `HttpContextBase` and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I don't see in your code where do you register the `HttpContextBase` itself... Try to register the `AutofacWebTypesModule` with `builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());`

Comment: Yes I just saw this now on their website. Do I register `AutofacWebTypesModule` first before I do `builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Request)`..?

Comment: I this case the registration order should not matter.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks to `nemesv`.

I ended up replacing:

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Request)
     .As<HttpRequestBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Response)
     .As<HttpResponseBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Server)
     .As<HttpServerUtilityBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Session)
     .As<HttpSessionStateBase>()
     .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

...with just:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
```

It works now.  Not sure what the difference is but the code in the module looks exactly the same as mine above.

Comment: If you check the source code of the [AutofacWebTypesModule](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Source/Autofac.Integration.Web.Mvc3/AutofacWebTypesModule.cs?r=94f70ab10f4d65991c600e2e80171ce4847589e6) you can see that you have left out the most important line  `builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
                .As<HttpContextBase>()
                .InstancePerHttpRequest();` which registers the `HttpContextBase`